# PHP some urls in arabic object not found using xampp

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, xampp, arabic

I am using htaccess redirection as follows

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Hence all urls should be redirected to index.php and it does, I am working on a website where I am using parts of url as multilingual, url encoded as it should be, this works fine with languages like spanish and russian but I am getting a problem with some links in arabic, they do not redirect to index.php instead I get the `Object not found` 404 error while using xampp for example,

```
http://localhost/sitework4/ar/%D8%A7%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D9%84
```

the above is a url including arabic url encoded, when entered in chrome it displays the decoded arabic, it works fine and redirects to index.php

```
http://localhost/sitework4/ar/%D9%85%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%AA
```

the url above is again arabic encoded, this does not work, it does not redirect to index.php instead it gives me

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 404

localhost
Apache/2.4.25 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2j PHP/5.6.30
```

I am not sure this is an error related to xampp or something is wrong with the URL standards I am using, it is not a problem with using non english characters as russian works fine with all cases, it might be problem related to the RTL nature of the arabic characters.

here are some more examples

```
http://localhost/sitework4/ar/%D9%83%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AC%D8%A7%D8%AA
```

this works

```
http://localhost/sitework4/ar/%D9%85%D9%86-%D9%86%D8%AD%D9%86
```

this does not

Comment: Your rule is always working for me for all the URLs you've provided.

Comment: @anubhava have you tried on XAMPP local server, this works on my godaddy server, I have this problem on my local server

Comment: I don't have `XAMPP` but I have `MAMP` as I am on OSX.

Comment: Aun, Did you fixed this issue? I do have same on Xampp and working fine in Mamp